# Delete Item from linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

So I've tried to write a function to delete one element of a linked list.
Unfortunately it doesn't work with the first item and I don't get why not

So what I was thinking is that if I want to delete the first item of a list I just "leave it out" and directly return the second item.

Here is my function:

```
node_t * deleteListItem(node_t * head, int n) {
    node_t * first = head;
    node_t * middle = NULL;
    node_t * last = NULL;

    int count;

    if (n == 1) {   /* not working */
        middle = head;
        head = head->next;
    }

    else {

        for (count=1; count <= n; count++) {
            last = middle;
            middle = first;
            first = first->next;
        }

        last->next = first;
    }

    free(middle);

    return head;
}
```

Would appreciate the help

Comment: show how do you call your function

Comment: you also do not check for the second border case: the last node. You need to add the check if `n` is not larger than the list size.

Comment: are you sure it's not working for the first element ? Once just comment the else loop and check it. It should work

Answer (score 0):

Change the reference from head instead, using pointer to pointer:

```
node_t * deleteListItem(node_t ** head_ref, int n) {
  node_t * first = *head;
  node_t * middle = NULL;
  node_t * last = NULL;

  if (n == 1) {   
    middle = *head;
    *head_ref = (*head)->next;
    free(middle); 
  }
  
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I currently work with linked lists as well, and I have written the following function to delete the n-th node from the linked list:

```
struct node *delete_node_n(struct node *start, long n) {
    long node_counter = 1;
    struct node *ptr, *preptr;
    preptr = NULL;
    ptr = start;
    // Case 1: Empty list
    if (start == NULL) {
        printf("List is empty. Nothing to delete.\n");
        return start;
    }
    // Searching for the n-th node
    while (ptr->next != NULL) {
        if (node_counter == n) {
            break;
        }
        preptr = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->next;
        node_counter++;
    }
    // Case 2: We have less than n nodes in the list
    if (node_counter < n) {
        printf("We have less than %ld elements in the list. ", n);
        printf("Nothing to delete.\n");
        return start;
    }
    // Case 3: All other cases
    if (preptr == NULL) {
        start = ptr->next;
    }
    else {
        preptr->next = ptr->next;
    }
    free(ptr);
    return start;
}
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

> If you don't want free-head, use

```
 if (n == 1) { 
        middle = head;
        return head->next;
    }
```

> If you want to free previous head and return new head, use

```
if (n == 1) { 
        middle=head;
        head= head->next;
    }
```